# Surpassing NULL Values

Tags: crystal-reports

I am creating a crystal report in which  i have to ![enter image description here][1] show address in this format for every school

```
ADD1
ADD2
ADD3
CITY
DIST
PINCODE
```

and i am fetching data from database, all the above column have some NULL values in it like for SCHOOL A - ADD1,ADD2,ADD3 have NULL values and for school  B ADD2,ADD3 and CITY have NULL values and same like rest schools have some null values now when i am writing formula for first school

```
IF ISNULL({TEMP_PAY.ADD1})THEN
(
IF ISNULL({TEMP_PAY.ADD2}) THEN
(
IF ISNULL({TEMP_PAY.ADD3})THEN
(
IF ISNULL({TEMP_PAY.CITY})THEN
(
IF ISNULL({TEMP_PAY.DIST})THEN
{TEMP_PAY.PIN}
ELSE
{TEMP_PAY.DIST}
)
ELSE
{TEMP_PAY.CITY}
)
ELSE
{TEMP_PAY.ADD3}
)
ELSE
{TEMP_PAY.ADD2}
)
ELSE
{TEMP_PAY.ADD1}
```

then the first address of all the schools are showing correct but when i put same formula with other parameters then first Scool give duplicate CITY and rest scool are the same and some gets correct

i want that where there is NULL it should escape the field and give the next field which have some value for the all above fields help me for the same as soon as possible as i have searched lot for the same issue but did not get any help....

Regards
Sanjeev

Answer (score 0):

To the extent I understood your problem.... try below solution.

Since you are looking to pick next value if present value is `NULL` then you can use function `NEXT`.

```
IF ISNULL({TEMP_PAY.ADD1})THEN
NEXT({TEMP_PAY.ADD1})
ELSE IF ISNULL({TEMP_PAY.ADD2}) THEN
NEXT({TEMP_PAY.ADD2})
ELSE IF ISNULL({TEMP_PAY.ADD3})THEN
NEXT({TEMP_PAY.ADD3})
ELSE IF ISNULL({TEMP_PAY.CITY})THEN
NEXT({TEMP_PAY.CITY})
ELSE IF ISNULL({TEMP_PAY.DIST})THEN
NEXT({TEMP_PAY.DIST})
ELSE
NEXT({TEMP_PAY.PIN})
```

Let me know if it helps